# possible to restrict the duplicates in jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm using json autocomplete for filter the text from database in php codeigniter. I wish to filter the duplicate entries like "Apple", "Apple" could possible to show the one entry "Apple". Following code is for used for filtering

```
$(function() {
        $( "#partnumber" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: base_url+"/suggest/part",
                data: { term: $("#category").val(), brand: $("#brand").val(), pname: $("#partname").val(), partid: $("#partnumber").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                     response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

Controller

```
function part()
{
    $term = $this->input->post('term');
    $brand = $this->input->post('brand');
    $pname = $this->input->post('pname');
    $part = $this->input->post('partid');
     $sts = 0;
    if (strlen($part) < 2) break;

    $rows = $this->suggest->part(array('keyword' => $part,'category' => $term, 'brand_name' => $brand,'p_name' => $pname, 'pres_sts' => $sts));

    $json_array = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row)
         array_push($json_array, $row->part_number);

    echo json_encode($json_array);
}
```

Model

```
function part($options = array())
    {
        $this->db->select('part_number');
        $this->db->like('ctr_name', $options['category']);
        $this->db->like('brn_name', $options['brand_name']);
        $this->db->like('prt_name', $options['p_name']);
        $this->db->like('present_status', $options['pres_sts']);
        $this->db->like('part_number', $options['keyword'], 'after');
        $query = $this->db->get('partnumber');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

please help me for solve this issue.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this before your select `$this->db->select('part_number');`

```
$this->db->distinct();
```